# Catalyst XML datafeed

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to output the data from an XML file datafeed, the support documents are pretty poor and I'm having trouble looping through the XML.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [@attributes] => Array (
        [version] => 6 [type] => WEB [date] => 20120220 ) 
        [account] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
        [@attributes] => Array (
            [code] => XXXX 
        ) 
        [sites] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
            [site] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                [@attributes] => Array ( 
                    [code] => XXXX 
                ) 
                [name] => Name [address1] => Address 1 [address2] => town [address3] => UK [county] => County [postcode] => Postcode [phone] => 0123456789 [fax] => 0123456789
                [vehicles] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                    [vehicle] => Array ( 
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                            [@attributes] => Array ( 
                                [code] => 5956 [new] => N
                                [engineSize] => 998 
                                [mileage] => 8000 
                                [type] => MC 
                                [reg] => XXX 
                                [regDate] => 20070414 
                                [created] => 20110928090130 
                                [modified] => 20110928090130 
                            ) [manufacturer] => Honda 
                            [description] => CBR 1000 RR-7 
                            [colour] => Black 
                            [body] => Motorcycle 
                            [fuel] => Petrol 
                            [status] => In Stock 
                        ) 
                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                            [@attributes] => Array (
                                [code] => 5958 
                                [new] => Y 
                                [engineSize] => 125 
                                [type] => MC 
                                [created] => 20110930090254 
                                [modified] => 20110930090254 
                            ) 
                            [manufacturer] => Honda 
                            [description] => WW125EX2A 
                            [colour] => BLACK(NHA35) 
                            [body] => SCOOTER 
                            [status] => In Stock 
                            [category] => SCOOTER 
                        )
                    ) 
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

The data is loaded by:

```
$request = 
    "<"."?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?".">".
        "<download account='XXXX' password='XXXX' version='6' request='EXP' format='XML' dealer='XXXX' vehicles='Y' />";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml", "Content-Length: " . strlen($request)));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.catalyst-findit.co.uk/download.php');
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
print_r($xml);
```

I'm mainly interested in the vehicle data, which I have tried to load by:

```
echo (string) $xml->vehicles->vehicle[0];
```

Although this doesn't seem to work.

Be grateful if anybody could offer any advice :)

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** XML file (displaying only two vehicles for easy reading):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<findit xmlns="http://www.catalyst-findit.co.uk/download" version="6" type="WEB" date="20120220">
<account code="XXX">
<sites>
<site code="BRI">
<name>XXX</name>
<address1>XXX</address1>
<address2>XXX</address2>
<address3>XXX</address3>
<county>XXX</county>
<postcode>XXX</postcode>
<phone>01472 123456</phone>
<fax>01472 123456</fax>
<vehicles>
<vehicle code="XXX" new="N" engineSize="998" mileage="8000" type="MC" reg="XXX" regDate="20070414" created="20110928090130" modified="20110928090130">
<manufacturer>Honda</manufacturer>
<description>CBR 1000 RR-7</description>
<colour>Black</colour>
<body>Motorcycle</body>
<fuel>Petrol</fuel>
<status>In Stock</status>
</vehicle>
<vehicle code="XXX" new="Y" engineSize="125" type="MC" created="20110930090254" modified="20110930090254">
<manufacturer>Honda</manufacturer>
<description>XXX</description>
<colour>BLACK(NHA35)</colour>
<body>SCOOTER</body>
<status>In Stock</status>
<category>SCOOTER</category>
</vehicle>
</vehicles>
</site>
</sites>
</account>
</findit>
```

Comment: what is the error ? please try `curl_error` to get error

Comment: No error is shown, the `print_r` shows the data above, I'm just having trouble accessing the vehicle data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath to search for specific node data.

```
$text = <<<EOF
... XML data ...
EOF;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($text);
# register xpath prefix for default namespace
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('__ns', $namespaces['']);
# get first vehicle data
$result = $xml->xpath('//__ns:vehicles/__ns:vehicle[1]');
# get all vehicles in array
$vehicles = $xml->xpath('//__ns:vehicles/__ns:vehicle');

print_r($result); # or
echo($result[0]->colour); 

foreach ($vehicles as $v) {
    echo ($v->colour . "\n");
}
```

Comment: And I tested and fixed (it has to use namespaces) sample code :)

Comment: Thanks! That works great, if possible could you demonstrate it within a loop so that the vehicle number doesn't have to be specified?

Comment: I added more sample code. Without [1] in xpath you get all vehicles (as stated in comment) in array.